# How can I map my Bamboo tablet to the entire screen after increasing screen resolution?

Tags: resolution, screen, wacom

The physical drawing area on my Wacom Bamboo MTE-450 pen tablet corresponds perfectly with the edges of the screen when the resolution is 1024x768. However, when I increase it to 1152x864, the tablet is still only mapped to the 1024x768 pixels in the upper left portion of the screen, so the pen reaches the edge of the tablet before the cursor actually reaches the edge of the screen.

How can I utilize the full screen without going back to 1024x768?

I'm running 12.04, 64-bit.

Answer (score 1):

[This page](http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=1656089) taught me how to map my generic tablet input to just one of my monitors (I have two, stacked vertically).  The middle section describes messing around with the coordinate transformation matrix.  To map my tablet to my top monitor I had to run the command:

```
xinput set-prop "HUION KentingK58" --type=float "Coordinate Transformation Matrix" 1 0 0 0 .5 0 0 0 1
```

You will likely need to scale up in x and y, but can probably get away with using the same method.